# jquery - Using Lightbox plugin with blob from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, lightbox

So I am trying to incorporate the LightBox plugin in order to have pop up images: [LightBox Info](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9#getting-started)

However my php code code uses an `img` tag rather than an `a` tag as Lightbox so requires. It seems the href and src conflicts when I try it. The images and everything display correctly and it is just a matter of using LightBox with my code. I was wondering if any of guys know how to do it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="/var/www/html/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/var/www/lightbox2-master/dist/js/lightbox.js"></script>

  <title>Greeting Cards</title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../../chromevers.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/catbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/lightbox2-master/dist/css/lightbox.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
include '/var/db_file.php';
include '/var/www/WideImage/lib/WideImage.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($theDb,$usr, $pass, "images");
mysqli_select_db($con, "images");

$query = "SELECT * FROM Greeting_Cards";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$images = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $images[] = $row['image'];
}

echo '<div id ="gallery">';

foreach ($images as $image) {
  $image = WideImage::loadFromString($image)->resize(300, 300);
  echo '<img id="database" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image) .'" />';
}
echo '</div>';

mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you didn't include lightblox.js ? have to tried to change your img into a's ? <a href="images/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>

Comment: Check your console what error it show???

Comment: I got confused and typoed! Also Saty, no errors show up. The calls to the js and css file should be in order now. And I don't know how to do a href to an image that isn't on the filesystem. Like I mentioned before, the images are taken from the mysql database.

Comment: And Random I can't do that since I don't have a hard link to reference to since the information is stored on the mysql database, which is the whole reason to this question.

Comment: Have you got a solution?

Comment: Check my answer below. Just updated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display my images another way. I uploaded the images to the server and stored the image path on the database. This way would make your website faster since you wouldn't be pulling a BLOB for lots of images and just would reference them on your server. Here is the line of code:

`echo '<a href="'. $image.'" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img id="dbImages" src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($reimage).'"/></a>';`

The `$image` variable is the `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()` call storing the image path. And `$reimage` is using the php library `WideImage` to  load an image from path. That library also has lots of other very useful image manipulation functions that you can use. Hope this helped!